# How to Insert Data in CakePHP with APIController?

Tags: php, android, mysql, cakephp

I have a **Function Order** in **Apicontroller.php**, I 've made ​​a note column, but why it does not want the record column store database to the Order, I am very confused to find where the data insert process in **CakePHP**, but to send the email had been a success, there is my code :

```
public function Order()
{
    $status                                     =   false;
    $message                                        =   ERR_04;
    $code                                           =   "04";

    $request["Order"]["service_id"]             =   empty($_REQUEST["service_id"]) ? "" : $_REQUEST["service_id"];
    $request["Order"]["user_id"]                    =   empty($_REQUEST["user_id"]) ? "" : $_REQUEST["user_id"];
    $request["Order"]["fullname"]                   =   empty($_REQUEST["fullname"]) ? "" : $_REQUEST["fullname"];
    $request["Order"]["email"]                      =   empty($_REQUEST["email"]) ? "" : $_REQUEST["email"];
    $request["Order"]["phone"]                      =   empty($_REQUEST["phone"]) ? "" : $_REQUEST["phone"];

    $request["Order"]["gender"]                     =   empty($_REQUEST["gender"]) ? "" : $_REQUEST["gender"];
    $request["Order"]["address"]                    =   empty($_REQUEST["address"]) ? "" : $_REQUEST["address"];
    $request["Order"]["lt"]                         =   empty($_REQUEST["lt"]) ? "0" : $_REQUEST["lt"];
    $request["Order"]["unit"]                       =   empty($_REQUEST["unit"]) ? "0" : $_REQUEST["unit"];

    $request["Order"]["city_id"]                    =   empty($_REQUEST["city_id"]) ? "" : $_REQUEST["city_id"];
    $request["Order"]["district_id"]                =   empty($_REQUEST["district_id"]) ? "" : $_REQUEST["district_id"];

    $request["Order"]["village_id"]                 =   empty($_REQUEST["village_id"]) ? "" : $_REQUEST["village_id"];
    $request["Order"]["date_order"]                 =   empty($_REQUEST["date_order"]) ? "" : $_REQUEST["date_order"];
    $request["Order"]["time_order"]                 =   empty($_REQUEST["time_order"]) ? "" : $_REQUEST["time_order"];
    $request["Order"]["time_finish"]                =   empty($_REQUEST["time_finish"]) ? "" : $_REQUEST["time_finish"];
    $request["Order"]["building_id"]                =   empty($_REQUEST["building_id"]) ? "" : $_REQUEST["building_id"];
```

// "Note" Variable Cannot Save in Database

```
    $request["Order"]["note"]                   =   empty($_REQUEST["note"]) ? "" : $_REQUEST["note"];
```

// I Don't Know Why

```
    $request["Order"]["total_maid"]                 =   empty($_REQUEST["total_maid"]) ? "1" : $_REQUEST["total_maid"];
    $request["Order"]["total_shift"]                =   empty($_REQUEST["total_shift"]) ? "1" : $_REQUEST["total_shift"];
    $request["Order"]["different_gender"]           =   empty($_REQUEST["different_gender"]) ? "0" : $_REQUEST["different_gender"];

    $request["Order"]["price"]                      =   empty($_REQUEST["price"]) ? "0" : $_REQUEST["price"];

    $request["Order"]["total"]                      =   $request["Order"]["total_maid"] * $request["Order"]["total_shift"] * $request["Order"]["price"];

    $request["Order"]["duration"]                   =   empty($_REQUEST["duration"]) ? "0" : $_REQUEST["duration"];

    $timeCoonvert                                   =   strtotime($request["Order"]["date_order"]." ".$request["Order"]["time_order"].":00");
    $request["Order"]["expired_order"]              =   date("Y-m-d H:i:s",mktime(date("H")+5,date("i"),date("s"),date("m"),date("d"),date("Y")));

    $this->loadModel('Order');
    $this->Order->ValidateCheckout();
    $this->Order->set($request);

    $error                                          =   $this->Order->InvalidFields();
    if(empty($error))
    {
        $status     =   true;
        $message    =   ERR_00;
        $code       =   "00";
        $save       =   $this->Order->save($request,array("validate"=>false));
        $ID         =   $this->Order->getLastInsertId();

        $this->Order->BindAll(false);
        $data       =   $this->Order->find('first',array(
                            'conditions'    =>  array(
                                'Order.id'  =>  $ID
                            )
                        ));
        $different_gender   =   ($request["Order"]["different_gender"] == "1") ? "Ya" : "Tidak";
        /****************** EMAIL NOTIFICATION ************************/        
        $search     =   array(
                            '[web_url]',
                            '[logo_url]',
                            '[cms_url]',
                            '[order_id]',
                            '[fullname]',
                            '[phone]',
                            '[address]',
                            '[email]',
                            '[date_order]',
                            '[time_order]',
                            '[total_maid]',
                            '[different_gender]',
                            '[total_shift]',
                            '[bank]',
                            '[total]'
                        );

        $replace    =   array(
                            $this->settings["web_url"],
                            $this->settings["logo_url"],
                            $this->settings["cms_url"],
                            $data["Order"]["order_id_display"],
                            ucwords(strtolower($data["Order"]["fullname"])),
                            $data["Order"]["phone"],
                            $data["Order"]["address"]."<br/>".ucfirst($data["Village"]["name"])."<br/>".ucfirst($data["District"]["name"])."<br/>".ucfirst($data["City"]["name"]),
                            $request["Order"]["email"],
                            date("d M Y",strtotime($data["Order"]["date_order"])),
                            substr($data["Order"]["time_order"],0,-3),
                            $data["Order"]["total_maid"],
                            $different_gender,
                            $data["Order"]["total_shift"],
                            str_replace("\n","<br/>",$this->settings['bank_payment']),
                            "Rp ".number_format($data["Order"]["total"],0,null,",")
                        );
        $this->Action->EmailSend('order', trim($request['Order']['email']), $search, $replace,array(),array(),"Order",$ID,"");
        $this->Action->EmailSend('order', "customer@gomaid.co.id", $search, $replace,array(),array(),"Order",$ID,"");
        /****************** EMAIL NOTIFICATION ************************/
    }
    else
    {
        $status     =   false;
        foreach($error as $k => $v)
        {
            $message    =   $v[0];
            break;
        }
        $code       =   "03";
        $data       =   null;
    }

    $out            =   array("status"=>$status,"message"=>$message,"data"=>$data,"code"=>$code,"request"=>$_REQUEST,"files"=>$_FILES);
    $json           =   json_encode($out);
    echo $json;
    pr($out);
}
```

This is my email receive ....

http://prntscr.com/a05oq9

But this is my table Orders still empty in note field ....

http://prntscr.com/a05pa5

Any have solution? i'm very stuck, i'm newbie inn CakePHP, please help me... im using Eclipse code Android to send data in web with CakePHP to database.

Comment: first check for validation on 'note' field in model `User.php` then set the debug code to 2 and if the problem still presist clear the `app/tmp/cache/model` delete all the files.

Comment: Thanks Valar, yes u are right! i'm have trouble in Cache.... i delete cache for User Model, Thanks .... you save my day ,,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sake of other people who might face this problem these are follow-up steps :

1. Clear `app/tmp/cache/model/*` all the files.
2. Set `debug` mode to `2`.
3. Make your `app/tmp` directory writable.

Note: Any alteration to the database schema will require to follow the steps `1` or `2` for `cakePHP` to detect changes made.

Comment: Thanks! i fix a problem with sampe follow-up your steps. but i fix in few month ago :)

Comment: No problem, happy to help.

Comment: This question help for another users read this post :). yeah!.